# Swapping rows of a table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows, swap

```
<tr id="r1">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Some Text1</td>
  <td>Some Text1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Some Text2</td>
  <td>Some Text2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r3">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Some Text3</td>
  <td>Some Text3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r4">
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Some Text4</td>
  <td>Some Text4</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r5">
  <td>5</td>
  <td>Some Text5</td>
  <td>Some Text5</td>
</tr>
```

I have a table which is organized as shown. What i'm trying to do, switching the rows of these table with user input.

For example: when user enters r1 and r3 the id's of these tables and "some text" parts should be changed and table should look like this.

```
<tr id="r3">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Some Text3</td>
  <td>Some Text3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Some Text2</td>
  <td>Some Text2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Some Text1</td>
  <td>Some Text1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r4">
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Some Text4</td>
  <td>Some Text4</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r5">
  <td>5</td>
  <td>Some Text5</td>
  <td>Some Text5</td>
</tr>
```

I tried to take values of one row to a temp variable and make a simple swap just like in OOP. However Jquery didn't let me do it :). What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Where are the inputs the ids are coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To swap two elements, the following logic can be used:

1. Insert a temporary placeholder after the second element
2. Move the second element after the first element
3. Replace the placeholder with the first element.

The implementation goes as follows:

```
var $elem1 = $("#r3"),
    $elem2 = $("#r1"),
    $placeholder = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");
$elem2.after($placeholder);

$elem1.after($elem2);
$placeholder.replaceWith($elem1);
```

In the previous sample, I have hard-coded the IDs. Assume that the user enters the IDs in fields with IDs `from` and `to`. Then, the implementation can be adjusted in this way:

```
var $elem1 = $("#" + $("#from").val()),
    $elem2 = $("#" + $("#to").val()),
    // same as first example,from line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to push the wanted rows to the head of the table.

```
table.prepend($(selector));
```

A simple implementation looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z98KG/4/):

```
$(function(){
    var table = $('#table');
    $('#swapper').keyup(function(event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var selector = '#' + $.trim(value).replace(/\s+/, ',#');
        if(selector) {
           table.prepend($(selector));
        }
    });
})
```